# What is method to get URL before tab redirect in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, geturl

I have developed a Add-on for Firefox.

It has a redirect link:

```
https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2FAdd-ons%2FCode_snippets%2FTabbed_browser&ei=3pfhU-TMIMPo8AXhg4GoAw&usg=AFQjCNGYBJDxF8FAEl3gxl1DcqTes93HFQ&bvm=bv.72197243,d.dGc
```

This link redirects to:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser
```

I am using this code to get redirect link before redirect

```
    var doc = event.originalTarget;
    var origEl = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(origEl.tagName === 'A' || origEl.tagName === 'a') {
             alert( gBrowser.currentURI.spec);
     }
```

It gives:

```
https:// developer. mozilla. org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser
```

But I need the previous redirect link.

I think `gBrowser.currentURI.spec` get current  Url of tab. I searched on Google but didn't find method to get original redirect link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gBrowser.webNavigation.referringURI
```

This will give you the current tab only. If you want of a specific tab then go:

```
var tabIndex = 0; //first tab
var referredFromURI = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[tabIndex].linkedBrowser.webNavigation.referringURI;
```

This isn't really the redirected from, but the referred from. But it works. If there is no referred URI than this property is `null`.

Also the person who downvoted your question is a loser. Good question you asked.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the question but it seems the intention is to get it before it redirects. Is `referringURI` available before or after the redirect?

Comment: I try your solution but i get "xpconnect wrapped nsIUR". I need program return original link.

Comment: oh do a `.spec` so `referredFromURI.spec`

Comment: I try with input http://bit.ly/R9j52J. But it is not return http://bit.ly/R9j52J. I check some short link and some  301 redirect website . This code doesn't work ok.